# Parse Mulit-Rooted XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to grab multiple attributes from data stored in xml column in SQL Server.

The XML data is multi-rooted and I'm unable to get any data beyond the "

This is a snippet of the XML:

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
     xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
     xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
     xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
    <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
        <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:CommandTimeout="300">
            <s:AttributeType name="GmID" rs:number="1" rs:writeunknown="true">
                <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
       </s:ElementType>
    </s:Schema>
    <rs:data>
            <z:row GmID="550733" ReadingTime="2019-09-23T15:44:58" DataSequenceNumber="132978"/>
    </rs:data>
</xml>

<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
     xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
     xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
     xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
     <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
        <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:CommandTimeout="300">
            <s:AttributeType name="GmID" rs:number="1" rs:writeunknown="true">
                <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            </s:ElementType>
    </s:Schema>
      <rs:data>
            <z:row GmID="550733" ReadingTime="2019-09-23T15:44:58" DataSequenceNumber="133008"/>
          </rs:data>
</xml>
```

How can I grab all of the attributes that exist under the "

Answer (score 0):

You can grab any of the attributes using following syntax.
If performance is important, you can declare names spaces for your query instead of using "*".

```
select x.value('./*:data[1]/*:row[1]/@DataSequenceNumber','int')
from  @x.nodes('/xml') as t(x)
```

will return:

```
132978  
133008
```